# SceneKit: How to detect contact without collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, scenekit

I'm looking for the best way (performace-wise) to detect contact between two objects that do not collide (not bounce off each other) in a SceneKit physics world.

I saw that SpriteKit has a `contactTestBitMask` and a `collisionBitMask` for physics bodies while SceneKit only has the latter. So there must to be another preferred way to get notified when objects have contact in SceneKit. I guess that calling   `contactTestBetweenBody:andBody:options:` in each frame for each object is not the best way to do it?

**UPDATE**
With iOS 9.0, Apple has added `contactTestBitMask` to `SCNPhysicsBody`. So this question will become obsolete soon.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having a physics body act as a sensor seems like a fairly basic bit of functionality.

Comment: I went with the accepted answer below (physicsField)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question deserves a full tutorial. In short, each physics body has a categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask.

**categoryBitMask**
This is the bit that represents the body.

**collisionBitMask**
This is the bit that represents which bodies collide with it.

By default (when assigned a physicsBody) all bodies collide with the exception of a kinematicBody, which act special. Objects don't collide with it. But don't get confused, it can collide with other objects when manually moved (such as by dragging it with a finger).

**How to handle!!!**

Assign your bodies whether it be static or dynamic. Assign there category and collision mask. If the mask match up they collide. How about an example!

**These bodies collide with each other**

```
bodyA.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 4;
bodyB.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 8;

bodyA.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 8;
bodyB.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 4;
```

**These don't collide**

```
bodyA.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 4;
bodyB.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 8;

bodyA.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
bodyB.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
```

Noticed I used categories by power of two. This is because the contactDelegate uses bitwise AND to compare. Read up on bitwise if you don't understand. It will really help.

**These bodies collide without physics**

EXAMPLE: You have a hero that runs through a ghost and you want to know that it happened without either one being effected. Such as bouncing off each other.

```
bodyA.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 4;
bodyB.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 8;

bodyA.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
bodyB.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
```

So the following code is designed so that bodyA(your hero) runs through bodyB(ghost).

```
bodyB.physicsField.categoryBitMask = 4
```

Noticed that the above is a physicsField.catagoryBitMask.  It is assigned a 4 so that it matches up with bodyA.

```
let collisionField = SCNPhysicsField.customFieldWithEvaluationBlock(){ 
    (_, _, _, _, _) in 
    WHAT U WANT TO DO ON CONTACT
}

bodyB.physicsField = collisionField
```

The physicsField is not the shape of your geometry unfortunately.  Its default is the shape of its bounding box or sphere/elliptical if you set the physicsField property usesEllipsoidalExtent to "true/yes"

The area of effect can be changed using the physicsFields halfExtent property like so...

```
bodyB.physicsField.halfExtent = SCNVector3Make(.5, .5, .5)
```

The above will extend the field of a box the size of (2, 2, 2) to (2.5, 2.5, 2.5).

**EDIT**: If they still collide, try removing the physicsbody from bodyB (this will remove all physics simulation from the node). I don't think it will be a problem as long as the catagory and collision bitmask are assigned properly.

This is the best method I could find. All coding is from my head, with the support of Apple docs, so may not be exactly right but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question. I'm not looking for a way to make objects collide, which is what you describe. I'm looking for a way to detect contact between objects that are set up to not collide (on purpose). Like when you have a power-up in a platformer and want to detect when your character runs through it, but don't want a physical collision between the two objects.

Comment: Sorry Dorian,  I made an edit. Let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the best way is to just set the mass so small on a kinematic body that the other one will pass through it.

sensorBox.physicsBody.mass = 0.00000000001; // super tiny mass makes it a "sensor"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your scene's physics world can call a "contactTestBetweenBody: andBody: withOptions...    this works great.

### Usage

```
[myScene.physicsWorld contactTestBetweenBody:(SCNPhysicsBody *) andBody:(SCNPhysicsBody *) options:(NSDictionary *)];
```