# SceneKit two nodes are not colliding

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, physics

I have two SCNNodes that are Kinematic and aren’t colliding, I’ve set the contactDelegate and the physics bodies are scaled correctly. I can see that the objects and physics bodies are colliding when I debug the app.

One of the bodies is a child node to a parent node that moves around the scene, while the other body is a physicsBody for a node that does not move

```
    let aShape = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 15, chamferRadius: 0)

    let aNode = SCNNode(geometry: aShape)
    aNode.position = SCNVector3(0,2,10)
    aNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: aShape, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale : 0.02]))
    aNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
    aNode.physicsBody?.allowsResting = false

    pNode?.addChildNode(aNode)
    aNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 4
    aNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 8
    aNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading ([SceneKit: How to detect contact without collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065933/scenekit-how-to-detect-contact-without-collision)), I set both nodes to have static physic bodies and it works :)